# Как сделать отслеживание звонков в Android?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать отслеживание звонков в моём приложении для Android. Я читал в интернете как это сделать, но при тестировании возникает ошибка:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\vladi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:14: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest>.
```

Что это за ошибка и как её исправить? Если нужно, вот AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компоненты андроид приложения (Activity, Service, Receiver, ContentProvider) надо указавыть внутри тэга application, а не вне его.

Просто перенесите `receiver` в тело тэга `application`

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!